# Steganography and hiding messages

Tags: steganography

Is it possible to hide strings of text in one picture without coupling the strings in a file? I have only been able to find tools that allow for one.

Comment: Sure. You combine the "secrets" into a single file.

Comment: but one cannot inject separate strings of text to an image? they must be put in a file first? Because as I understand, image has a capacity, so if within capacity I don't see why this is not possible?

Comment: You didn't ask about text strings. Perhaps you need to expand on your question, your expectations, your context, and your requirements...

Comment: You can hide more than one text string in an image, and depending on the tool, you can certainly hide multiple different strings in a single image.